# undefined object in reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a container that holds search bar inside a `form element` consisting of two inputs, `from` and `to`, and a `button`.

On my form submit function, I create an `OBJECT` called `query` and it equals to:

```
const query = {
            from : this.state.from,
            to   : this.state.to
        };
```

then I pass this query object as an argument to an action that have created :

```
this.props.fetchPlaces(query);
```

In my `action.js` inside my `fetchPlaces` I have :

```
var skypicker = {   
        flyFrom : query.flyFrom,
        flyTo   : query.toCity,
    };
```

I want to be able to pass `flyFrom` and `flyTo` to an api that later returns flights from `flyFrom` to `flyTo` which return results as JSON!

ofcourse i have to parse them to the URl, but at the current state flyFrom  and flyTo are undefined, Am I doing this currectly?

Comment: Check if   `query.from` and `query.to` are "undefined".

Comment: @VTodorov no they are  well undefined!

Answer (score 0):

It’s query.from and query.to but not query.flyFrom and query.toCity

Check right one below

```
var skypicker = {   
    flyFrom : query.from,
    flyTo   : query.to
};
```

I generally do this

request body:

```
 let data = {};
  data.firstName = this.state.firstName;
  data.lastName = this.state.lastName;
  data.email = this.state.email;
  data.password = this.state.password;
  data.sex = this.state.sex;
  this.props.registerUser(data);
```

action call:

```
export function registerUser(data) {

 return dispatch => {
dispatch(registerUserRequest());
return ajax.post(URL_PREFIX + '/auth/register/', data)
  .then(res => {
    dispatch(registerUserSuccess(res.data))
    setTimeout(function(){
      dispatch(push('/login'))
    }, 2000)

  })
  .catch(errors => {
    dispatch(registerUserError(errors))
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: i get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: flyFrom is not defined`

Comment: there is another way, instead of sending an object, I can just send the values and in my action I can create an object there so I can parse later!, i am not sure which way is the better way!

Comment: There is no much difference. Both cases same. One more thing start avoid using var instead start using let and const. its ES6 standards.

Comment: @ Hemadri Dasari thanks for the advice I will keep in mind from now on!

Comment: Can you try this way let skypicker = {}  
    skypicker.flyFrom = query.from;
    skypicker.flyTo   = query.to;

Comment: @ Hemadri Dasari same undefined results!

Comment: Why are you trying to call the fields of that object in action call? you no need just pass as it is like I mentioned in my post. If you still want to check object fields then try let obj = JSON.stringify(data); and then check obj.flyFrom you will be able to read the data

Comment: @ Hemadri Dasari I created the object like how u did, but I dont undetsand what happends after return!

Comment: Sorry can't help you much without knowing what you doing in your action call (: I gave you real time action call example.

Comment: my action basically creates some parameters, that I can later use pass it to an API and get results in form of JSON. do u understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: See action calls are basically for two reasons. 1. An action call to make an API call to the server. 2. An action call to store the data in redux without an API call. I don't understand what parameters your action creates. Anyway try your best

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing properties that you haven't set. The names differ between `query` and `skypicker`.

Try creating `skypicker` like this:

```
var skypicker = {
    flyFrom: query.from,
    flyTo:   query.to
};
```

Comment: Looks like @Hemadri had the same idea. Jinx!

Comment: when I do console.log I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: flyFrom is not defined `

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(skypicker);` and `console.log(query);`?

Comment: when I do  `console.log(skypicker);` it returns the correct object, if I do `console.log("--> "+skypicker);` it returns `-->[object Object] ` and `console.log(query);` it returns `{from: "value", to: "vlue"}` vlue being what I set in my inpu, so this returns correct object!

Comment: In the case of `console.log("-->"+skypicker);`, the skypicker object is being concatenated with the string `"-->"`, which calls the toString method on the object (`[object Object]`). If you really want the formatting of `"-->"`, try `console.log("-->", skypicker);`. Without the concatenation call, `console.log` inspects the properties of the object. If `console.log(skypicker);` looks correct, what is the problem?

Comment: @ Ben Harris thanks, I realize that I was wrong on that!